# AngularJS: Issues integrating a directive using ng-repeat with an external plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to build a directive which will link a dropdown (select) to an external jquery plugin.

This is the code of my templateUrl view for the directive:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option data-ng-repeat="(key,label in opts)"
     value="{{key}}">{{label}}</option>
</select>
```

This is the link function of my directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
   {
       console.log( scope.opts );
       console.log( $(element).html() );
       $(element).chosen(); //call external plugin
   }
```

The problem here is, for some reason, when the `link` function is called, the select is not yet populated with options using the ng-repeat. So when I call the jquery plugin, it shows an empty dropdown, even though later on the select is populated with options.

The output of `console.log( scope.opts );` correctly shows the object with options, while `console.log( $(element).html() );` only shows:

`<!-- ngRepeat: (key,label) in opts -->`

Is there a way to be notified when the ng-repeat has populated the select, so I can only then call the external plugin?

Comment: Angular does not have any mechanism to reliable detect when the DOM has rendered. Your best bet is to use `$timeout`. Said that, why dont you look at `choosen` directive, i found one here https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen.

Comment: @Chandermani Thanks, but I want to write my own. Either case, `$scope.$watch` on the `scope.opts` variable from `link` seems to work, if I call the `$(element).chosen()` from within the `$scope.$watch`, it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue (of not knowing when dom has been updated by angularJS), was to use `$timeout`. However, with dropdowns, `ngOptions` is super hard to integrate with external plugins. So, I would recommend anyone else who wants to integrate the chosen or any other plugins with dropdowns, to just use `ngRepeat` and `ngSelected` using normal `<option>s` instead of `ngOptions`